# Value retrieval from the Multiple selection dropdown in excel

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I am trying to make calculation from my dropdown menu.
This is how my dropdown looks.
Category

- AAA
- BBB
- CCC
- DDD

These are the values associated with my dropdown.
Category Category value

- AAA 1
- BBB   2
- CCC 3
- DDD 4

I added VBA code for multiple selection and also added simple Vlookup formula to retrieve the value of category.

```
=VLOOKUP(E2;Sheet2!I2:J5;2;)
```

With the VBA code, i am able to select all three category and also remove the selected category later. But I am failing to retrieve the sum of selected category. For e.g. I want if customer chooses category AAA & CCC, he/she should be able to see sum as 4. Also if customer first chooses all three category and then removes one of the category then also the sum should get updated. I am not getting how do i update my Vlookup formula to get the sum.

Here is my VBA code for multiple selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Updated: 2016/4/12
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                '                If xValue1 = xValue2 Or _
                '                   InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) Or _
                InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") Then
                If InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, xValue2 & ", ", "") ' If it's in the middle with comma
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, ", " & xValue2, "") ' If it's at the end with a comma in front of it
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Then        ' If it is the only item in string
                    xValue1 = ""
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                Target.Value = xValue1 & ", " & xValue2
            End If
            jumpOut:
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note : Look at using `If.....then....elseif...else....end if` or `Select case` so you can get rid of `GoTo jumpOut`

Comment: Instead of Vlookup, I should code in VBA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of coding in VBA, you can simply use this function and it will work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!A1:I4;Sheet1!A2))*Sheet2!B1:B4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like so for the summation part.  I have my reference table A1:B4.  I called using `Get_Sum("A,C,D")`

```
Function Get_Sum(strInput As String) As Double

Dim a() As String
Dim v As Variant
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim l As Long

a = Split(strInput, ",")
Set r = Range("a1:b4")

Get_Sum = 0

For Each v In a
    l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(v, r.Columns(1), 0)
    Get_Sum = Get_Sum + r.Cells(l, 2)
Next v

Set r = Nothing
Erase a

End Function
```

Calling like so

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '   Where A5 is the validated cell and B5 is the sum result

    If Target = Range("a5") Then
        Range("b5").value = Get_Sum (Target.Value)
    End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: With this code, My multi select option is not working.

Comment: In 6 mins :o) How are you calling it, i cant see your machine.  LIke I added in the post, when you have `Get_Sum("AAA,BBB,CCC")`?  Have you changed the reference table to where your data is ?

Comment: I am trying to add this function inside if statement

Comment: Get_Sum (''AAA,BBB,CCC') is only possible when customer selects AAA, BBB, CCC from the dropdown menu. I associated a value for my dropdown menu and with the help of Vlookup i am able to get the associated value. But when i try to do multi select, my VBA code doesn't calculate the sum of the value associated with the selected menu.

Comment: In your `IF...Intersect` statement, you can remove\comment out your code. Call this function and send the string of all your selections in the combobox. Other thing to note is, remove `On Error Resume Next` from your code as it just hides the issues

Comment: I am not so good with the coding. Could you please explain in detail how do i proceed